# repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Tags: 16.04

I installed MikTex following this [tutorial](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome-apt-error-ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D6BC243565B2087BC3F897C9277A7293F59E4889

echo "deb http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu xenial universe" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/miktex.list

sudo apt-get update
```

I got this note message:

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

How to get rid of this?

Comment: This message means that your system is 32-bit, but repository has only [64-bit packages](http://mirrors.mi.ras.ru/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/setup/deb/dists/xenial/universe/). Usually on Ubuntu and Debian texlive is more functional then MikTeX. Why you do not want to install `texlive` package?

Comment: I have a 64 bits CPU. Yes, I removed and purged miktex and installed texlive instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For you information. If you have 64-bit CPU and 64-bit only repository you should have the following line in *sources.list*:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu xenial universe
```

Here `[arch=amd64]` did the trick.

But texlive is better.