# MiKTeX installation problems

Tags: 18.04, package-management, latex, aptitude

I am trying to fix a MiKTeX installation on Ubuntu 18.04, or at least I would like to remove it and all its packages in order to install TexLive.

I tried to install it a couple of weeks ago, following https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex-unx, and i got

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

I didn't have much time to fix the problem, so I didn't do anything. 
Gong back to it this morning, I tried this solution on the last step:

[repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023009/repository-http-miktex-org-download-ubuntu-xenial-inrelease-doesnt-support)

Then I run:

```
 rob@rob-Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install miktex
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
 distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
 or been moved out of Incoming.
 The following information may help to resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 miktex : Depends: libhunspell-1.3-0 (>= 1.3.3) but it is not installable
          Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not installable
          Depends: libmpfr4 (>= 3.1.3) but it is not installable
          Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And, at the end

```
 rob@rob-Ubuntu:~$ sudo aptitude install libhunspell-1.3-0
 No candidate version found for libhunspell-1.3-0
 Unable to apply some actions, aborting
```

Nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

I would like 
1- to install Miktex correctly  **OR** 
2- cancel anything related to it, and install TexLive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dpkg -l miktex` will return if MiKTeX is installed. To wipe MiKTeX : MiKTeX Console -> Cleanup -> Reset the TeX installation, then

```
sudo apt-get remove miktex
sudo apt autoremove
```

To install TeXLive on 18.04, you can install one of

1. texlive-base
2. texlive-latex-recommended
3. texlive
4. texlive-latex-extra
5. texlive-full

The first package `texlive-base` will install just the basics of LaTeX. `texlive` or `texlive-latex-extra` will suit the majority of users. Go with `texlive-full` if you have plenty of space and don't mind nonessential packages.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Comment: That's what I got trying
 'rob@rob-Ubuntu:~$ MiKTeX Console
  MiKTeX: command not found'

Comment: At which step did you get this?

Comment: Trying to follow your comment! I just typed "MiKTex Console" to open it, and it gave this to me. (I am not really sure I actually managed to install MiKTeX given the numerous error messages I got during the installaton process , those that I copied in my question. So maybe it actually never installed ? )

Comment: There are no packages apparently! 
I just thought something actually got installed since I found a couple of miktex source files in ' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ '  and ' /var/lib/apt/lists/miktex.org_download_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease'

Comment: `dpkg -l miktex` will return if miktex is installed.

Comment: Did you proceed installing texlive?

Comment: Yes, I installed texlive-publisher and it is working fine! 
Thanks